# как ограничить количество потоков в threading

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность

всем привет! есть код:

```
for line in friends:
    threading.Thread(target=messages, args=(line,)).start()
```

который успешно рассылает людям сообщения. возник вопрос: как ограничить количество потоков, если например friends больше 50 строк? и нужно ли потоки как то закрывать после их работы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor):

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
    for line in friends:
        executor.submit(messages, line)
```

Answer (score 1):

`pool.map()` лучше всего подходит для списков. Пула обычных потоков нет в модуле `threading`, но в модуле `multiprocessing` есть интерфейсы к `Thread`-ам.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def messages(line):
    pass

pool = ThreadPool(processes=8)
results = pool.map_async(messages,friends)
```

Потоки закрывать не нужно. Их удалит GC, если их никуда не сохранить перед запуском.

В Питоне также есть старые добрые [threading.Semaphore](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#semaphore-objects)